# Searching multidimensional array and returning key

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to see if a certain value exists in this array, and if so, return the key:

```
$letter = 'B';

$array[0]['ID'] = 1;
$array[0]['Find'] = 'A';
$array[1]['ID'] = 2;
$array[1]['Find'] = 'B';

$found = array_search($letter, $array);

if ($found) { 

  unset($array[$found]);

}
```

From what I can tell, this is not dropping the array elements when the value is found. Any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the key you find. For the example you posted use a `foreach` to search in the sub-arrays.

Comment: I think you may try array_pop for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking in that specific column:

```
$found = array_search($letter, array_column($array, 'Find'));
unset($array[$found]);
```

- This is a multidimensional array so extract the `Find` column and search
- You need to loop and `unset()` if `Find` is not unique

Or alternately:

```
$array = array_column($array, null, 'Find');
unset($array[$letter]);
```

- Extract all the columns but index them by `Find` so you can just `unset()` that

Comment: For the 2nd solution +1

Comment: ^ Sure, I'm in. ;-)

Comment: So, should we concentrate on all of the `array_column()` or `array_count_values()` questions today?

Comment: ...only if you want to ;-) I'm not hot with arrays; I like learning from you guys.

Answer (score 2):

Use array_filter to save only elements without B

```
$arrayWithoutB = array_filter($array, 
                function($i) use($letter){  return $i['Find'] != $letter; });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search in the `Find` field, and return the corresponding `ID` field as in your example you want to have a match in the fourth line:
`$array[1]['Find'] = 'B';`

Then you need to actually iterate the outer dimension like so:

```
foreach ($a in $array) {
  if ($a['Find'] == $letter) {
    // found, return the ID field
    return $a['ID'];
  }
}
```

Let me know if you want to return something else, hope this helps :)